# Automatic Generate Localizable strings is not working iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localizable.strings

I have a project with primary login, signup, and home screen functionalities. In my project, the string keys are not taking the value from localizable strings. It is not getting from the bundle path. Here is the code where I am calling the strings file. It works fine in the English language but not working in the french language.

**Screen Shot:-**

**Add language**

[image: Screen Shot]

**Automatic created two files one is English and another one is french.**

[image: Screen Shot]

**When I run the app in the English language works fine, but When I change the language from the scheme, I get the error below when I run the app in the french language.**

[image: Screen Shot]

**Change Language**

[image: Screen Shot]

**Localizable.strings**

**French**

[image: Screen Shot]

**English**

[image: Screen Shot]

**View Controller and Localization Extension**

[image: Screen Shot]

**Alert Enum**

[image: Screen Shot]

**Question:** How to run the app in french and English language?

Can someone please explain to me how to do this, I've tried with the above but have no results yet. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to regenerate the localizable of `Main.storyboard`. it's an heavy task each time for storyboard/xib translations. For instance, open the `Main.storyboard` as source code (xml), and look for the OxB-JS, etc. I guess it disappeared, you removed/recreated it so its "id" if not there anymore.

Comment: @Larme, I recreated it again. Delete the old one. But still, the same issue occurs. Could you please give me any idea or any example which helping me?

Comment: Unable to "load" strings files seems to be in fact the issue, it's strange. It's rejecting the slash. Do you still have that error message?

Comment: @Larme Yes. Now I added the Localizable.strings file. Check the updated question, please.